# The Drupal 7 Cache seems to not be cleared as it should be

Tags: caching, drupal, redis, varnish, drush

I have recently taken over the maintenance and the evolution of a Drupal 7 Website, it is due to pass over to D8 but not in the near future,

I have a lot of issues with the frontal cache,
Here is the list of all the modules and/or caching systems used in the server :

- Varnish : Now disabled,
- Redis : Only in module, not in server,
- Cache Expiration Module,
- OpCache seems activated, but only for 1mn caching according to
  sysadmin,
- MemCache activated also,

What  did try :  Clearing all Drupal cache using drush cc all,
Even tried verbose and it just returned 2 lines saying some temp folder being rewritten ? and of course a success response,

I asked the sysadmin to reload/reboot Apache to see if anything was in the server side, but the more I dig the more I think it is the Drupal cache which is not being cleared like it should be,

Result of `php drush.php -v cc all` :

```
Executing mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_HSxa1g --database=[DB]--host=[HOST] --port=[PORT]--silent  < /tmp/drush_jis8o8

Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_BFZzky --database=[DB]--host=[HOST] --port=[PORT]--silent  < /tmp/drush_99YRFp

'all' cache was cleared.                                                [success]

Command dispatch complete                                               [notice]
```

I update any template file, let's say node--[content-type].tpl.php,
I deploy, and clear the cache, either using the back-office button or the drush cc, (usually both).

The page displays with the new code, but whenever I just refresh it, it goes into a random display, sometimes the old one, sometimes the new one,
Some pages display node template version that are one or two week old.

For example, every thing that is not being visited by any anonymous user seems to be not caching, like XML feeds, they do get renewed and not cached.

Comment: `The page displays with the new code, but whenever I just refresh it, it goes into a random display, sometimes the old one, sometimes the new one, Some pages display node template version that are one or two week old.` – Absolutely clear this isn't Drupal but some server-side caching.

Comment: Thanks,

I have the same issue on the admin area, sometimes a new field appears, and dissapears, can you expand on why you are sure it is not drupal and is server side caching ?,

Comment: Just out of curiosity (has happened to me in the past) do you have CloudFlare or similar service? I almost go nuts once clearing cache of a WordPress site and it was the CloudFlare cache the one I was hitting.

Comment: Not to my knowledge, i just asked the sysadmin to de-activate the memcache/memcached services, and still the same issues, i will try to investigate on every caching that could be present in the server.